# Creating a New AKS Cluster with the Latest Kubernetes Version and Migrating Objects from an Existing Cluster

Tags: azure, migration, kubernetes, version

I currently have an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster running on Kubernetes version 1.19.7 with a "Basic" load balancer type. Instead of upgrading the existing cluster, I want to create a new AKS cluster with the latest Kubernetes version and a "Standard" load balancer type. Additionally, I need to migrate all the existing Kubernetes objects (pods, services, deployments, etc.) from the old cluster to the new one.

I'm looking for guidance on the best practices and steps to accomplish this migration process. Here are some specific questions:

**Migrating Kubernetes Objects:**

1. What is the recommended method for migrating all Kubernetes objects (deployments, services, etc.) from the old cluster to the new one?
2. Are there any tools or scripts that can help automate this process?
3. How can I ensure a smooth transition without downtime for my applications during the migration?

**DNS and Networking Considerations:**

4. What considerations should I keep in mind regarding DNS and networking when migrating between AKS clusters?
5. Are there any potential challenges related to DNS resolution or service discovery?

I appreciate any insights, tips, or step-by-step guidance from experienced Kubernetes and Azure AKS users who have tackled similar cluster migrations.

I still didn't try anything, I want to know the best practices before starting